# Spiritual weapon- what happens if an enemy tries to grab it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, cleric

I have a level three cleric and just cast spiritual weapon for the first time last session.  It was in a fight against a group of goblins, so the DM thought it'd be funny for one of them to see the magical floating weapon and try to grab it for themselves.

Based on the text of the spell, none of us can figure out what would happen if a creature tried to grab a spiritual weapon.  It's dealing force damage, so it doesn't seem like it'd be ghost-like and have the creature's hand just pass through it.  But there also aren't any stats listed, so it doesn't seem like it'd make sense for something to be able to grab it and do something like a strength contest to try and move/stop it.

We resolved it at table by just saying the weapon is incorporeal until it attacks, at which time *yadda yadda magic* and it deals damage.

According to the actual rules, what should have happened there?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate :) FYI, being a duplicate isn't a bad thing (it helps others find similar question who pose it like you have), but if you feel that yours is different, please let us know and we can help you update and remove the link if necessary.